# Cannot Load Hive Table into Pig via HCatalog

Tags: hive, apache-pig, cloudera, hcatalog

I am currently configuring a Cloudera HDP dev image using [this tutorial](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Quick-Start/cdh4qs_topic_3.html) on CentOS 6.5, installing the base and then adding the different components as I need them. Currently, I am installing / testing HCatalog using [this section](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_19.html) of the tutorial linked above.

I have successfully installed the package and am now testing HCatalog integration with Pig with the following script:

```
A = LOAD 'groups' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader(); 
DESCRIBE A;
```

I have previously created and populated a 'groups' table in Hive before running the command. When I run the script with the command `pig -useHCatalog test.pig` I get an exception rather than the expected output. Below is the initial part of the stacktrace:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2245: Cannot get schema from loadFunc org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Cannot get schema from loadFunc org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1608)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1547)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:518)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:991)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:412)
...
```

Has anyone encountered this error before? Any help would be much appreciated. I would be happy to provide more information if you need it.

Comment: have you tried specifying the schema?

Comment: I have, thank you for the suggestion. It turns out my HBase Thrift server was not configured properly. Once I had it configured and the URL added to my hive-site.xml file, everything worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by HBase's Thrift server not being proper configured. I installed/configured Thrift and added the following to my hive-xml.site with the proper server information added:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://<!--URL of Your Server-->:9083</value>
    <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
</property>
```

I thought the snippet above was not required since I am running Cloudera HDP in pseudo-distributed mode.Turns out, it and HBase Thrift are required to use HCatalog with Pig.